# Write csv file in php, but also apply sort/filter

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am trying to write a csv file in php, so that when user clicks on an icon, it will generate a csv file using data from my database.

Everything works and I have three columns: name, date, age

I was wondering if in php, I can apply the filter.
For example, in excel, I can click on sort & filter -> filter on the first row, which will create a drop down menu with several features.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not from a CSV file. It can be added manually in MS Excel after the CSV file has been opened; or you can create a real Excel file with the filter area pre-defined which will have the selection boxes and sort options available when the end-user opens the file in MS Excel

Comment: You would have to use a library such at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to do that. CSVs are confined to text by nature, the added fancy stuff (sorts, graphs, etc.) is provided through the various spreadsheet applications (Excel, Numbers, OpenOffice, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort/filter while extracting from the database, then write the filtered and sorted data into the CSV file.

If you do this by taking inputs from a form on your web page, make sure that you validate the inputs server-side.